# Node.js Deployment through Elastic Beanstalk using Docker

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, npm-install

I am trying to deploy a node.js react based isomorphic application using a Dockerfile linked up to Elastic Beanstalk.

When I run my docker build locally I am able to do so successfully. I have noticed however that the npm install command is taking a fair amount of time to complete.

When trying to deploy the application using the eb deploy command it is pretty much crashing the Amazon service or I get an error like this:

> ERROR: Timed out while waiting for command to Complete

My guess is that this is down to my node_modules folder being 300MB big. I have also tried adding an artifact declaration into the config.yml file and deploying that way but get the same error.

Is there a best practice way of deploying a node application to AWS Beanstalk or is the best way to manually setup an EC2 instance and relying on Code Commit git hooks?

My Dockerfile is below:

```
FROM node:argon 
ADD package.json /tmp/package.json
RUN npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
RUN npm set progress=false
RUN cd /tmp && npm install --silent
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ADD . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8000

CMD npm run build && npm run start
```

...and this is my config.yml file:

```
branch-defaults:
  develop:
    environment: staging
  master:
    environment: production
global:
  application_name: website-2016
  default_ec2_keyname: key-pair
  default_platform: 64bit Amazon Linux 2015.09 v2.0.6 running Docker 1.7.1
  default_region: eu-west-1
  profile: eb-cli
  sc: git
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should change your platform to a more current one (I'm using
   docker 1.9.1, and there might be newer versions)
2. I'm using an image from docker hub to deploy my apps into beanstalk. I build them using our CI servers and then run a deploy
   command that pulls the image from docker hub. This can save you a
   lot of build errors (and build time) and is actually more in touch with the Docker
   philosophy of immutable infrastructure.
3. 300MB for node_modules is not small but should present no problem. We deploy this size of dependencies and code regularly.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I will try updating our Docker version and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: NP, but notice this was only a general tip, and most probably won't solve your problem. You will definitely get better results by using a container repository (Like AWS ECR or docker hub) to manage your images, and pull them into beanstalk without building them every time.

Comment: Ok, I will have a look at this. I have not really looked at the container service as yet as I have had no problems with my containers by just using a Dockerfile and running eb deploy before now.

Comment: That's cool, I found out that the more I managed to minimize the amount of work being done on deploy I've not only minimized build time, but gained a lot of free time by not having to debug errors emerging from running build on different environments. Build once, run anywhere is not just a clever logo.

Comment: How would the Dockerfile look on the Docker Hub when I commit it to the registry as I am already pulling the node:argon image to setup my node.js server?

Comment: The way Docker works is by building the image layer by layer. In your case - node:argon will be the base layer, and every command executed by the dockerfile will create another layer. Then you will push the new image into docker hub. Docker hub will store the actual build environment you created locally, not only the dockerfile.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much. That is really helpful. Just started putting up a container into ECS. Will let you know how I get on!

Comment: For sure, happy to help. Another word of advice - I will say you should avoid ECS, and stick to beanstalk when running containers on AWS. ECS is pretty crappy, in my opinion.

Comment: Unforuntely this does not seem to have done the trick as AWS is now failing with the message:

Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)... allocate memory Failed to build Docker image aws_beanstalk/staging-app: ng build context to Docker daemon 96.77 kB

I am really not sure what is going on as I have successfully built and run the same image locally :-(

Comment: Seems to suggest this maybe a problem with Docker v1.9.1 though: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=709006

Comment: Are you using a t1.micro for your app? If so, try changing to t2.micro or perhaps even a stronger instance. I suspect this issue has been resolved already as i've run the same setup recently and it worked fine

Comment: Allocate memory failure is also a different error msg than the one mentioned in the thread you linked to, and makes a lack of reasources highly plausible. I would definitely try a stronger instance to try and solve this.

Comment: Hmm. I did consider this as it does seem to point to a lack or resources. I will try the t2.micro and move up from there if there are still issues. Thanks for getting back to me Yaron.

Comment: Sure thing, if this really fixes your situation make sure to mark the question as answered please.

Comment: Upgrading the server has indeed fixed the issue. Thank you so much for all your help on this Yaron.

Comment: Was a pleasure, happy I could help out.